# Synaptics Driver will not install windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, drivers, synaptics-touchpad

I cannot install the Synaptics touchpad driver on my laptop.

It is a Clevo we550eu, windows 8.1 pro. I am trying to install the latest driver version for clevo, v17.0.9.1 for windows 8.1. I have tried:

1. Installing by clicking the setup.exe in the download, ignoring a message saying I have a prior version installed.
2. Uninstalling all prior versions by going to device manager and uninstalling the driver, both the system and touchpad parts to the driver, and then installing the update by using the setup.exe
3. Same as 2. but with a restart in between the uninstall and install
4. Starting in clean boon / safe mode and installing
5. Uninstalling all synaptics drivers using the pnputil.exe command interface tool, using pnputil.exe -e then pnputil.exe -d oem*.inf
6. Installing the version from this link http://www.ryukent.com/2013/11/fixed-install-synaptics-touchpad-driver-windows-8-1/
7. deleting the synaptics folder in the program files folder before install as in 1.

In all cases, running the setup.exe causes the setup to run apparently fine but 'mouse properties' does not show the synaptics tab. In devices, it says the mouse is using a microsoft driver version 6.3.9600.16384.

After method 5. & 6., pnputil.exe -e showed that the driver had installed by not properly as it is not shown in the 'mouse properties' and no entry in the program files is made.

n.b I have read [Synaptics - Windows 8.1, updating Synaptics failed](https://superuser.com/questions/690671/synaptics-windows-8-1-updating-synaptics-failed) and tried its recommendations

I have also tried installing in disable driver signing mode

What should I do?!

Comment: At the moment, using pnputil.exe -e lists the synaptics drivers as oem1.inf & oem2.inf, so they are installed, albeit incorrectly. the system drivr for the touchpad cannot be unistalled as it says Deleting the driver package failed :One or more devices are presently installed using the specified INF.

Comment: v16.2.21.0 works, but i want more recent version to prevent crashing when busy