# ASUS VivoBook S200E Windows 8.1 Touchpad Precision Settings missing

Tags: windows-8.1, touchpad, asus-laptop

I am having problem with [Touchpad Precision settings](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/touchpad) on my ASUS VivoBook S200E, which is running Windows 8.1.

I have successfully installed update KB2975719 which should bring the Touchpad Precision settings to my system but I can only see these few settings:

Since I am not having reputation at least 10 I can't post image. When I am going to `(metro) Settings > PC and devices > Mouse and Touchpad` I can see only Click delay option in the section with Touchpad.

I tried to look for proprietary drivers at ASUS website but it seems that for Windows 8.1 [there are none](http://www.asus.com/in/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/ASUS_VivoBook_S200E/HelpDesk_Download/), so I assumed that in Windows 8.1 drivers for my touchpad should be included in system.

I also tried to install older drivers in compatibility mode but they are really buggy - they work properly but sometime when I use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> in Chrome to get my cursor to search bar, Chrome crashes. After I uninstalled drivers this never happened again, but I am not able to scroll and double-tap with my touchpad. You can imagine that this issue is really annoying and counterproductive.

Does anyone else experience this kind of problems? How did you solve them?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same setup and problem. The following solution works perfectly for me.

- Install the latest synaptics drivers as per [these instructions](https://superuser.com/questions/690671/synaptics-windows-8-1-updating-synaptics-failed).
- Install the Asus Smart Gesture touchpad driver for Window 8.0 from [the official downloads page](http://www.asus.com/in/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/ASUS_VivoBook_S200E/HelpDesk_Download/). Choose Windows 8, not 8.1. The 8 drivers work for both versions, but hasn't been added in the 8.1 section.

I am not sure if you need the synaptics drivers, so you could first try with just the Asus drivers.

Comment: I tried it and now I am testing it. I'll let you know if the problem still occurs. Thanks for help

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't help. I encountered another crash of Chrome right after using touch input and then pressing ALT+D